# How to incorporate custom weights with heteroskedasticity with generalized least squares?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I want to model a linear regression with heteroskedasticity, but also utilizing custom weights that are completely independent of the covariance matrix so that I can weight observations as I would like to. 
 
I imagine that I could just incorporate a weight matrix into the covariance matrix in the standard GLS approach but I'm struggling to justify to myself exactly how this would work. My guess would be that I just take my covariance matrix to be VW where V is the actual covariance matrix and W is my diagonal matrix of weights.